# A confusion regarding absolute motion in SRT

Tags: special-relativity

Suppose i am inside a uniformly moving spaceship and I send a light beam perpendicular to the direction of motion towards the opposite wall.Since the spaceship is moving and according to special relativity light doesn't feel any sort of "kick" on account of the motion of the spaceship, shouldn't the light beam pass by the ship once it bounces off the wall (instead of coming right back at it), thereby letting me know that I am moving?

Comment: Is the "wall" you are firing at outside or inside the spaceship? Also, what do you mean by *"according to special relativity light doesn't feel any sort of "kick" on account of the motion of the spaceship"*?

Comment: You just misinterpreted my question.The wall is inside the spaceship.I mean according to SRT light doesn't have the horizontal component of velocity with which the spaceship is moving and hence it should miss the target

Answer (score 1):

If the spaceship is moving uniformly with respect to someplace else and not accelerating, then you are in an inertial frame. In such a frame there is no measurement you can do to tell that you are the one moving with respect to that other place. Similarly, if you are in a train with no windows that is moving at constant speed and you throw a ball towards the wall it will bounce right back at you.

Comment: But that is classical relativity you are talking about, the ball will bounce back at you because it carries the horizontal component of the velocity of the train which isn't the case with light

Comment: It is also the case for light. If you are moving with respect to the outside world uniformly, it is the same as though you were standing still and the outside world moving. Only if the spaceship were to be accelerating the beam of light would deflect.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the spaceship is moving and according to special relativity light doesn't feel any sort of "kick" on account of the motion of the spaceship,

The absence of a "kick" you're referring to is related to the *speed* of light, not its direction. If you run very quickly and point the flashlight in front of you, the light's speed, as measured by *any* observer, is $c$. That it's not $v+c$ is a manifestation of the absence of "kick."

The motion of the spaceship, though, can influence the *direction* of the light. So, in your example, the *velocity* of light has a component along the direction of the ship, the speed of which is the same as the ship. But since the magnitude of the velocity of the light must be exactly $c$, the component of the light's velocity going perpendicular to the ship must have a speed less than $c$.

Comment: So the motion of spaceship adds a horizontal component of velocity to the light; is that what you are trying to say? But this leaves the question open as to why it shouldn't add a horizontal component when the light beam is shot in the same direction as that of velocity of spaceship.

Comment: "Why" is difficulty; its a postulate in SR that speed of light is constant.